# How can I protect MVC Hangfire Dashboard

Tags: c#, visual-studio, model-view-controller, hangfire

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 MVC, and I installed "Hangfire" to perform scheduled tasks. (http://hangfire.io/)

How can I protect the Web Monitoring UI page (http://localhost/Hangfire) with a password?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me give the entire code for a RestrictiveAuthorizationFilter:
This way you can handle authorization however you desire.

Assuming you have the OWINStartup class added.

**OWINStartup.cs**

```
using Owin;
using Hangfire;
using Hangfire.Dashboard;

public class OWINStartup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {        
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("String");
        DashboardOptions options = new DashboardOptions()
        {
            AuthorizationFilters = new IAuthorizationFilter[]
            {
                new MyRestrictiveAuthorizationFilter()
            }
        };
        app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", options);
    }
}
```

**RestrictiveAuthorizationFilter.cs**

```
using Hangfire.Dashboard;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Owin;

public class MyRestrictiveAuthorizationFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public bool Authorize(IDictionary<string, object> owinEnvironment)
    {
        var context = new OwinContext(owinEnvironment);

        return context.Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    }
}
```

**Notice:** using System.Collections.**Generic**;

References: 
https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/202

https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/hangfire/latest/hangfire.pdf (page 20)

Hangfire.Dashboard.Authorization version: **2.1.0**

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look to the [documentation](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/configuring-authorization.html)

In short.
You can use already created authorization filters or implement your own

```
using Hangfire.Dashboard;

public class MyRestrictiveAuthorizationFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public bool Authorize(IDictionary<string, object> owinEnvironment)
    {
         // In case you need an OWIN context, use the next line.
         var context = new OwinContext(owinEnvironment);
         return false;
    }
}
```

Additional information:

Also you can take a look to the [special package Hangfire.Dashboard.Authorization](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire.Dashboard.Authorization) which contains the logic which you needed

Answer (score 0):

Set this up in your Startup.Cs

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        //TODO
        app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
        {
            Authorization = new[] { new MyAuthorizationFilter() }
        });
        app.UseHangfireDashboard();
        var options = new BackgroundJobServerOptions { WorkerCount = 1 };
        app.UseHangfireServer(options);    }
```

Create this class, it allows authenticated users to see the Dashboard

```
public class MyAuthorizationFilter : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
{
    public bool Authorize(DashboardContext context)
    {
        var httpContext = context.GetHttpContext();

        // Allow all authenticated users to see the Dashboard (potentially dangerous).
        return httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    }
}
```